# Program crashes after adding QSlider to app

Tags: qt

I am trying to use this slider in my app https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html

in my class, I added

```cpp
#include <QSlider>
 
class...

    QSlider *slider;
```

Window class

```cpp
    slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
    boxLayout->addWidget(slider);
    group->setLayout(boxLayout);
```

I am seeing the slider in my window like this :

[image]

But whenever I click on anything, the program shuts down with this information
`The program has unexpectedly finished.` Whenever I remove the code from above, my program works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: Use a debugger and see where it crashes.

Comment: It just says signal `SIGSEGV` meaning : Segmentation fault

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: When  you start it in a debugger you will see the stack trace ... learn to use your tools.

Answer (score 1):

I try this and it works :

first add `GroupBox` widget in UI and then write this :

```
slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);

QBoxLayout *boxLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
boxLayout->addWidget(slider);

ui->groupBox->setLayout(boxLayout);
```

I **new** `QBoxLayout`  and I don't know you do it or not but the program didn't crash for me.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to bind a value from 1-100 and show next to the slider and pass it to an integer value in the code?

Comment: yes, but it is another question ask it in another thread.